# OFFSET / INDIRECT function trouble

Tags: excel

I have two sheets within a workbook, the first with several thousand lines of expenses, separated by individuals, and the second a summary of totals and such.

On the second sheet, I've created a reference to the first to insert each individual's name (i.e. B4: ='Card Transactions'!D89).  I'm having difficulty with the syntax for returning the total of each individual's total, which is in a predictable cell in the first sheet relative to the name (down 1, right 7).

I've tried the following:
=offset(indirect(B4),1,7) with only a reference error in return.  This seems like it should be relatively simple but I'm not having any luck. . . any suggestions?

Comment: `='Card Transactions'!K90` is one down and 7 over.

Comment: exactly:  I want person's total to be listed next to their name on the second sheet.

Comment: so put that formula in C4.  B4's formula is one cell why can't this one be that?

Comment: the offset formula is the one I tried in C4.  It's not working

Comment: No the formula I gave in you in my first comment.

Comment: I understand how to fix the reference - I'm trying to do it for hundreds of people without entering the cell references by hand - I want to use the cell with the names as a point of reference because each account has a different number of entries but they're all the same one down and seven over from the name.

Comment: @jay I don't think you understand, Scott Craner already answered your question. Paste his formula into cell C4, and *drag down*. You should notice that "magically" the references change dynamically to *always* grab the value in the cell which is one down and seven over.

Comment: I did them individually and trying not to repeat the task

Comment: If you posted some test data we may be able to give you better formula than doing it by hand and ones that do not require the use of Volatile functions.

Comment: dragging down would work if they were already aligned - they're not.  One name may be fifty lines from the previous name and the next is fifteen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this:

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT(MID(FORMULATEXT(B4),2,300)),1,7)
```

note:

- this only works if the formula in B4 only contains the one cell reference.
- This is a volatile function and will cause a noticeable lag in calculations if used too many times.

Comment: @jay please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: @ScottCraner I literally LOL'd when I saw your picture was changed to that smiley face with a cap on.

Comment: if I reduce the number of characters from 300 will the function lag less?

Comment: @jay no, it is not the MID() that is doing the lag.  The INDIRECT and OFFSET are the volatile functions.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work for you as long as your data follows these rules:

- Your columns have headers
- The names are all in the same column
- And you are able to set the range with row numbers and not just full columns

**Let's say your first sheet is set out like this:**

[image: Screenshot 1]

**And you want your second sheet like this**:

[image: Screenshot 2]

**And your sheets are named:**

- Sheet1
- Sheet2

**This is the formula in B2 of Sheet2:**
`=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$H$9,MATCH(A1,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$9,0)+1,MATCH("Column 8",Sheet1!$A$1:$H$1,0))`

**And here's what it does:**

[image: Screenshot 3]

- Your index array is the entire blue area, this can be the whole sheet but can't be a full column reference, ***the row number must be specified***. In this example, the index array is `$A$1:$H$9` and the `$` signs mean the range won't move when you drag down the formula, so they are important!
- Your first match finds the row number, it uses the name (in this case 'bart') as the lookup value, and the purple area as the array. In this example the row array is `$A$1:$A$9` and ***the row numbers must match the row numbers in the index array***. The match has a "+1" at the end, so it will find the matching row, then add one row down to get your offset.
- Your second match finds the column number, it will need to use ***the name of your column***.  In this example the column array is `$A$1:$H$1` and ***the column letters must match the column letters in the index array***.

Let me know if this doesn't fit your problem, I'm sure we can figure it out.

Thanks.

Comment: This is helpful, thank you for the suggestion - the data in this particular sheet is not in an array as you've laid out here - but I know this will come in handy for me elsewhere. . .